# Sort by highest value in any field

Tags: bash, sorting, awk

I want to sort a file based on values in columns 2-8?
Essentially I want ascending order based on the highest value that appears on the line in any of those fields but ignoring columns 1, 9 and 10. i.e. the line with the highest value should be the last line of the file, 2nd largest value should be 2nd last line etc... If the next number in the ascending order appears on multiple lines (like A/B) I don't care of the order it gets printed.

I've looked at using **sort** but can't figure out an easy way to do what I want...

I'm a bit stumped, any ideas?

Input:

```
#1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9    10
 A  0.00  0.00  0.01  0.23  0.19  0.07  0.26  0.52  0.78
 B  0.00  0.00  0.02  0.26  0.19  0.09  0.20  0.56  0.76
 C  0.00  0.00  0.02  0.16  0.20  0.22  2.84  0.60  3.44
 D  0.00  0.00  0.02  0.29  0.22  0.09  0.28  0.62  0.90
 E  0.00  0.00  0.90  0.09  0.18  0.05  0.24  1.21  1.46
 F  0.00  0.00  1.06  0.03  0.04  0.01  0.00  1.13  1.14
 G  0.00  0.00  1.11  0.10  0.31  0.08  0.64  1.60  2.25
 H  0.00  0.00  1.39  0.03  0.04  0.01  0.01  1.47  1.48
 I  0.00  0.00  1.68  0.16  0.55  0.24  5.00  2.63  7.63
 J  0.00  0.00  6.86  0.52  1.87  0.59 12.79  9.83 22.62
 K  0.00  0.00  7.26  0.57  2.00  0.64 11.12 10.47 21.59
```

Expected output:

```
#1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9    10
 A  0.00  0.00  0.01  0.23  0.19  0.07  (0.26)  0.52  0.78
 B  0.00  0.00  0.02  (0.26)  0.19  0.09  0.20  0.56  0.76
 D  0.00  0.00  0.02  (0.29)  0.22  0.09  0.28  0.62  0.90
 E  0.00  0.00  (0.90)  0.09  0.18  0.05  0.24  1.21  1.46
 F  0.00  0.00  (1.06)  0.03  0.04  0.01  0.00  1.13  1.14
 G  0.00  0.00  (1.11)  0.10  0.31  0.08  0.64  1.60  2.25
 H  0.00  0.00  (1.39)  0.03  0.04  0.01  0.01  1.47  1.48
 C  0.00  0.00  0.02  0.16  0.20  0.22  (2.84)  0.60  3.44
 I  0.00  0.00  1.68  0.16  0.55  0.24  (5.00)  2.63  7.63
 K  0.00  0.00  7.26  0.57  2.00  0.64 (11.12) 10.47 21.59
 J  0.00  0.00  6.86  0.52  1.87  0.59 (12.79)  9.83 22.62
```

Comment: Is it possible to write a program in another language, such as Java, to perform this operation?

Comment: Unfortunately not. I'm limited to bash...

Comment: JS, c++, anything?! Keeping in mind that you can run the resulting programs from the command line! :P

Comment: To be honest, I've never used Java / C++ and wouldn't know the first thing... I can possibly use python as a hesitant second preference but I mainly script in bash.

Comment: This is trivial with standard UNIX shell tools, no need to look at stuff you need to install yourself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Preprocess the data: print the max of columns 2 through 8 at the start of each line, then sort, then remove the added column:

```
awk '
    NR==1{print "x ", $0} 
    NR>1{
        max = $2; 
        for( i = 3; i <= 8; i++ ) 
            if( $i > max )
                max = $i;
        print max, $0
    }' OFS=\\t input-file | sort -n | cut -f 2-
```

Comment: Why `printf "%f %s\n", max, $0` instead of `print max, $0`? Why `print "x " $0` instead of `print "x", $0`? If you do the latter 2 it's more concise and then if you additionally set `OFS='\t'` then you don't need the `-d ' '` arg for `cut` since tab is it's default separator.

Comment: @EdMorton No reason.  Your excellent suggestions are added.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Another pure `awk` variant:

```
$ awk 'NR==1; # print header

     NR>1{ #For other lines,
         a=$2;
         ai=2;
         for(i=3;i<=8;i++){
             if($i>a){
                 a=$i;
                 ai=i;
                 }
             } # Find the max number in the line

             $ai= "(" $ai ")"; # decoration - mark highest with ()
             g[$0]=a;
         }

    function cmp_num_val(i1, v1, i2, v2) {return (v1 - v2);} # sorting function

    END{
        PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="cmp_num_val"; # assign sorting function
        for (a in g) print a; # print
    }' sortme.txt | column -t # column -t for formatting.

#1  2     3     4       5       6     7     8        9      10
A   0.00  0.00  0.01    0.23    0.19  0.07  (0.26)   0.52   0.78
B   0.00  0.00  0.02    (0.26)  0.19  0.09  0.20     0.56   0.76
D   0.00  0.00  0.02    (0.29)  0.22  0.09  0.28     0.62   0.90
E   0.00  0.00  (0.90)  0.09    0.18  0.05  0.24     1.21   1.46
F   0.00  0.00  (1.06)  0.03    0.04  0.01  0.00     1.13   1.14
G   0.00  0.00  (1.11)  0.10    0.31  0.08  0.64     1.60   2.25
H   0.00  0.00  (1.39)  0.03    0.04  0.01  0.01     1.47   1.48
C   0.00  0.00  0.02    0.16    0.20  0.22  (2.84)   0.60   3.44
I   0.00  0.00  1.68    0.16    0.55  0.24  (5.00)   2.63   7.63
K   0.00  0.00  7.26    0.57    2.00  0.64  (11.12)  10.47  21.59
J   0.00  0.00  6.86    0.52    1.87  0.59  (12.79)  9.83   22.62
```